# Problems with calendar updating from Outlook

Tags: calendar, microsoft

Recently my i-phone 5 stopped updating my outlook calendar.  I can update on the phone and it transfers to my computer but not vice-versa.  I am running Windows 7 Outlook 365 and ios 7 (I have not updated to 7.1.1).

Comment: which way does it not work?

Comment: It won't remove cancelled events or move altered events.  Also it won't show some new events.

Comment: let me understand your question, when you make changes on computer they do not show on phone, but the opposite is true

Comment: That is correct.  But, it's not consistent.  SOME events show up with the change and others do not. Example: I put an all day event on via Microsoft Outlook.  Then I had to change the event.  I changed the date and added information.  The old event is still present, but the changed and updated event is also present.

Comment: I have several outlook calendars and it seems that one in particular is causing the most problems.  I suspect it may have something to do with using the category option on Microsoft as any appointment I categorized disappeared on my i-phone.  Once I removed the category it came back.

Comment: sounds like you already found a bug, and the work around, congrats :)

Comment: Now if only I could figure out why deleted and moved items still show in their original place. :/

Comment: probably they get refreshed from the other site, so do it on both sites to test

Comment: ok so I edited an event on the i-phone and instantly it updated on outlook.  I made a similar edit on outlook and it didn't change on the phone.  I exited the program and locked the screen then went back into it.  The change was now loaded.  Yay.  But I still have an event I deleted last week in Microsoft still on the phone so still not sure what's going on.  I wonder if it's one that I had a labeled with a category, then changed, then removed the category.  Will have to continue experimenting...

Comment: sounds like you are a having fun....I am just a innocent bystander :) .. now answer your own question with stuff you did, and who knows you might even get some points.